# CSS - Rotate radial-gradient

Tags: html, css, radial-gradients

I have got a `<div>` with `radial-gradient`, but it is at a wrong angle. Changing the angle of simple `linear-gradient` is easy, but it has multiple gradients. I can't add `90deg` at the start, because it doesn't work.

Below is my gradient. The waves are from bottom to top, how can I turn them to make them from left to right (**I want to use only `background` property**)? Thanks for help.

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 100% 50%, transparent 20%, #ff0000 21%, #ff0000 34%, transparent 35%, transparent), radial-gradient(circle at 0% 50%, transparent 20%, #ff0000 21%, #ff0000 34%, transparent 35%, transparent) 0 -50px;
  background-size: 75px 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Comment: you may also consider changing background-position like i did in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48486932/8620333 to avoid the first cut wave

Comment: Thank you. I will use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. Swapped the values for the circles and background size.

```css
div {
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 100%, transparent 20%, #ff0000 21%, #ff0000 34%, transparent 35%, transparent) 50px 0, radial-gradient(circle at 50% 0%, transparent 20%, #ff0000 21%, #ff0000 34%, transparent 35%, transparent) 0 0;
background-size:100px 75px;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS `transform: rotate` property to rotate the div, instead of gradient. :)

```css
div {
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
background: radial-gradient(circle at 100% 50%, transparent 20%, #ff0000 21%, #ff0000 34%, transparent 35%, transparent), radial-gradient(circle at 0% 50%, transparent 20%, #ff0000 21%, #ff0000 34%, transparent 35%, transparent) 0 -50px;
background-size:75px 100px;
transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, but I want to use only `background` property

Comment: There must be a way to do it. Like in `linear-gradient`

Comment: The only way would be playing with the position of those `radial-gradients`. Theres no `rotation` for radials.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:before` pseudo class for the gradient background and then apply `transform` to the `:before`(will not affect `div`).

***Stack Snippet***

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 100% 50%, transparent 20%, #ff0000 21%, #ff0000 34%, transparent 35%, transparent), radial-gradient(circle at 0% 50%, transparent 20%, #ff0000 21%, #ff0000 34%, transparent 35%, transparent) 0 -50px;
  background-size: 75px 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>Content</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it is good, but I want to use only `background` property

Answer (score 1):

Simply change some values. You may also specify a `background-position` to avoid the first cut part of the wave:

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 100%, transparent 20%, #ff0000 21%, #ff0000 34%, transparent 35%, transparent), radial-gradient(circle at 50% 0%, transparent 20%, #ff0000 21%, #ff0000 34%, transparent 35%, transparent)-116px 0;
  background-size: 77px 57px;
  background-position: -5px 25px, 33px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```